# Sending long URLs via Mail using Rich Text decodes special characters

Tags: mail.app, email, big-sur, encoding

When I send long URLs via OSX Mail using Rich Text formatting, and there will be encoded characters in the URL they will get decoded. For example if the URL contains a very common `%2F`, then after the mail is sent it will get decoded into a slash (`/`, its textual equivalent).

Sketch, Figma, and other similar software generates such long URLs for the purpose of sharing the work with others, and these URLs when decoded are obviously not functional...

The only workaround that I was able to find out is to send mail using Plain Text, but this may not work for some (and I'd also prefer Rich Text).

I'm on Big Sur and I never thought I'd run into an issue like that in 2022...
Is there any fix for this?